# Replace a certain phrase from all the div and p and add image as background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to use javascript to replace a phrase like "hellokitty" with "hellocat" and add a background to the tags containing "hello"from all `<div>` and `<p>` tags in my html code.

I tried the following but it does not work,

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div>hellokitty!</div>
    <p>hellokitty!</p>
    <div>hellokitty!</div>
    <p>hellookitty</p>
    <span>hellokitty!</span>
    <script>
        document.getElementsByTag("div")[0].style.backgroundImage = "url('https://www.royalcanin.com/~/media/Royal-Canin/Product-Categories/cat-adult-landing-hero.ashx')";
    document.body.innerHTML =document.getElementsByTag("div")[0].innerHTML.replace(/I hate forest!/g, 'I love forest!');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And it doesnt work

Comment: `div` is not an ID....it's an element type.

Comment: You need to add `id` on your `div` if you want to use `getElementById("your_id")` @Charlotte45

Comment: I edited. I tried using by tag and trying only for the  first and it's still not working...

Comment: `getElementsByTagName`, not `getElementsByTag`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is quite possible.

Let's look at what you are trying to do:

1. Select all `<p>` and `<div>`'s on the page. For this we can use `document.querySelectorAll()`
2. Replace a certain string with another string. Just use `String.prototype.replace()`
3. If a string is replaced, change the background of that element. For this, we'll use `Element.style.background`

```js
// Select all div and p elements on the page. This returns a list-like object, called a HTMLCollection
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("div, p");

// Loop through the returned HTMLCollection
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  // Select current element
  var currentElement = elements[i];

  // Replace the string "hellokitty". We use regex so we can use the g(global) flag to match all occurances. We also use the i(case insensitive) flag.
  currentElement.innerHTML = currentElement.innerHTML.replace(/hellokitty/gi, function() {
    // This callback is called if the regex is matched, and should return the string to replace with.
    // I chose to use this to also set the background of the current element, but if there is going to be a bunch of occurances of the word within a single element it'd be better to check and set this once.
    currentElement.style.background = "yellow";

    // Return string to replace with
    return "hellocat"
  });
}
```

```html
<h3>These occurances should be replaced</h3>
<div>Here is some text hellokitty and here is some more</div>
<p>hellokitty</p>
<div>we are replacing the html so we can keep <b>hellokitty</b> styling tags and such</div>

<h3>And these should not be replaced</h3>
<p>i do not match the phrase hellokitten</p>
<span>and I am a <code>span</code>, not a <code>div</code> or <code>p</code>. hellokitty!</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

I used Jquery, so i don't know if it can help you, but here is my solution :

```
$.each($("body").find("div, p"), function(k, v) {
    $this = $(this);
    $this.text( $this.text().replace("hellokitty", "hellocat") );
    if ($this.text().match("hello")) {
        $this.css("background-image", "url('paper.gif')");
    }

})
```

Live version [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sa6bLukq/6/) (i change background-image to color because i can't load image on jsfiddle).

Comment: OP used the `jQuery` tag for some reason, so I guess your answer is relevant. Why do you filter `.is("div")`? `p` should have a background as well. Also, optimise your code by caching `$this=$(this)` once, instead of re-wrapping `$(this)` each time.

Comment: I miss read, i thought it was only div with background, anyway, i just edited with what you said, thanks!